# How to make select required upon parent option selected with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make subcategory required only upon PDF option selected from the category select.

I have tried this JavaScript but its not working.

```js
function getVal(ele){
  var element = document.getElementById("category")
  ele.value == "pdf" ? element.required =true : element.required =false
}

getVal(document.getElementById("subcat"))
```

```html
<select id="category" name="category" required>
  <option value="">select category</option>    
  <option>doc</option>
  <option value="pdf">pdf</option>
  <option>gifs</option>
</select>

<select id="subcat" name="subcat">
  <option value="">select type</option>
  <option>normal pdf</option>
  <option>other pdf</option>
</select>
```

But its not working, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jQuery:

```js
var $category = $("#category")
var $subcat = $("#subcat")

$category.on('change', function() {
    $subcat.prop('required', $(this).val() === "pdf")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category" name="category" required>
  <option value="">select category</option>       
  <option>doc</option>
  <option value="pdf">pdf</option>
  <option>gifs</option>
</select>

<select id="subcat" name="subcat">
  <option value="">select type</option>
  <option>normal pdf</option>
  <option>other pdf</option>
</select>
```

With pure JS:

```
var $category = document.querySelector("#category")
var $subcat = document.querySelector("#subcat")

$category.addEventListener('change', function() {
    $subcat.required = this.value === "pdf"
})
```

Comment: Both worked great thanks a lot @Christian Carrillo and please give like if my question was worth to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This runs before the user selected something from the menu.
Adding a `change` event listener to the select will do it.
Also, you're mixing up `ele` and `element`.

```
function getVal(ele) {
  ele.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("category")
    element.value == "pdf" ? ele.required = true : ele.required = false
  })
}
getVal(document.getElementById("subcat"))
```